# Performing paginated search on Active Directory using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to perform paginated search on Active Directory using `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.PageResultRequestControl`.

I do get the search results in pages, however, the `searchResponse` that I get does NOT have the correct `TotalCount` for total number of pages.

Is it not supported? Or am I missing something here?

This is sample code that I have used in order to implement above. I am using `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` to query Active Directory.

When `PageResultRequestControl` is added with page number, everything works perfectly except for `totalSize`.

For example, in this code

```
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(ldapDirectoryIdentifier, credential);
SearchRequest sr = new SearchRequest("", "(displayName=*)", System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree, new[] { "displayName"});
PageResultRequestControl pr = new PageResultRequestControl(50);
SearchOptionsControl so = new SearchOptionsControl(SearchOption.DomainScope);

sr.Controls.Add(pr);
sr.Controls.Add(so);

SearchResponse searchResponse;

while (true)
{
    searchResponse = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(sr);

    if (searchResponse.Controls.Length != 1 || !(searchResponse.Controls[0] is PageResultResponseControl))
    {
        totalPageCount = 0;
        return null;
    }

    PageResultResponseControl pageResponse = (PageResultResponseControl)searchResponse.Controls[0];

    totalPageCount = pageResponse.TotalCount;

    if (pageResponse.Cookie.Length == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        pageRequest.Cookie = pageResponse.Cookie;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As documentation says, the TotalCount property contains the estimated result set count (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.pageresultresponsecontrol.totalcount)

Comment: yes the documentation does say that.. but I am only seeing 0.